# How to determine download file name when there's no content-disposition

Tags: http, download, content-disposition

Take a look at this URL:

> http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-9.0.1&os=win&lang=nl

It is the direct link to download the latest version of Firefox. When you *execute* the URL in Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari, etc. they all suggest the file name "Firefox Setup 9.0.1.exe". If you look at the response headers there's no `content-disposition` header. The URL obviously also doesn't contain the name. Where do these browsers get the suggested file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the URL, the server sends a "302 Found" redirect response with `Location: http://mozilla.mirror.ac.za/firefox/releases/9.0.1/win32/nl/Firefox%20Setup%209.0.1.exe`

Your browser redirects here and this is where the filename comes from. If you install a proxy such as http://fiddler2.com/ (on Windows) you'll be able to see exactly what's going on.